# Change Author Name to Sitename on Frontend

Tags: posts, multisite, pages, author

How can I change the author name on the frontend to be the sitename instead without modifying theme?

I am basically looking for something that I can package as plugin on my site that will no longer show the authors name whatsoever on the posts or pages on the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify it through the `the_author` filter:

```
/**
 * Set the author name as the site title.
 */

! is_admin() && add_filter( 'the_author', 
    function( $author )
    {
        return get_bloginfo( 'name' ); 
    }
);
```

where we change the *author name* to the *site name* on the frontend with the help of the [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) function.